# Android Studio Refactor > Extract > Style Disabled

Tags: android, android-studio, refactoring

I am trying to extract style in android studio 0.8.9 using the refactor option. But it seems to be disabled for some reason. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project just in case and even restarting Android Studio, but nothing seems to enable the extract style option.

Do let me know if anybody else is facing the same problem or is there a way to solve this ?
Screenshot image: 
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I had the same problem.  Extracting styles is different in Android Studio:

You don't need to select text and choose `Refactor->Extract->Style`, just choose the menu option **With no text selected**.

So, just click anywhere inside the ImageView element (**Do not select any text**).  The refactor option should become available.

Comment: This should been accepted answer, migrating from Eclipse to Android studio can have some problems, this is one of it.

Comment: sometimes I wonder WHY Android-studio does not use common sense! if someone has selected few lines and then extract, pop up the extract window with those highlighted, checked. thats what people call Commmon sense. anyway thanks for answer

Comment: year 2022, option is not available...

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me without selecting any code. To extract layout you need to select the whole layout not just a part of it.